# Data Loss reading from one file, processing and writing to another? Python

Tags: python, file, csv, io

I wrote a script to transform a large 4MB textfile with 40k+ lines of unordered data to a specifically formatted and easier to deal with CSV file.

**Problem**:

Analyzing my file sizes, it appears i've lost over 1MB of data (20K Lines | *edit:* original file was 7MB so lost ~4MB of data), and when I attempt to search specific data points present in *CommaOnly.txt* in *sorted_CSV.csv* I cannot find them.

I found this really weird so.

**What I tried**:

I searched for and replaced all unicode chars present in the *CommaOnly.txt* that might be causing a problem.. No luck!

*Example:* \u0b99 replaced with " "

**Here's an example of some data loss**

A line from: *CommaOnly.txt*

```
name,SJ Photography,category,Professional Services,
state,none,city,none,country,none,about,
Capturing intimate & milestone moment from pregnancy and family portraits to weddings
```

*Sorted_CSV.csv*

```
Not present.
```

What could be causing this?

**Code:**

```
import re
import csv
import time

# Final Sorted Order for all data:
#['name',   'data',
# 'category','data',
# 'about',  'data',
# 'country', 'data',
# 'state',   'data',
# 'city',   'data']


    ## Recieves String Item, Splits on "," Delimitter Returns the split List
def split_values(string):
    string = string.strip('\n')
    split_string = re.split(',', string)
    return split_string


    ## Iterates through the list, reorganizes terms in the desired order at the desired indices
    ## Adds the field if it does not initially 
def reformo_sort(list_to_sort):
    processed_values=[""]*12
    for i in range(11):
        try:
            ## Terrible code I know, but trying to be explicit for the question
            if(i==0):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="name"):
                        processed_values[0]=(list_to_sort[j])
                        processed_values[1]=(list_to_sort[j+1])
                            ## append its neighbour

                ## if after iterating, name does not appear, add it.
                if(processed_values[0] != "name"):
                    processed_values[0]="name"
                    processed_values[1]="None"

            elif(i==2):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="category"):
                    processed_values[2]=(list_to_sort[j])
                    processed_values[3]=(list_to_sort[j+1])

                if(processed_values[2] != "category"):
                    processed_values[2]="category"
                    processed_values[3]="None"

            elif(i==4):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="about"):
                        processed_values[4]=(list_to_sort[j])
                        processed_values[5]=(list_to_sort[j+1])

                if(processed_values[4] != "about"):
                    processed_values[4]="about"
                    processed_values[5]="None"

            elif(i==6):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="country"):
                        processed_values[6]=(list_to_sort[j])
                        processed_values[7]=(list_to_sort[j+1])
                if(processed_values[6]!= "country"):
                    processed_values[6]="country"
                    processed_values[7]="None"

            elif(i==8):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="state"):
                        processed_values[8]=(list_to_sort[j])
                        processed_values[9]=(list_to_sort[j+1])

                if(processed_values[8] != "state"):
                    processed_values[8]="state"
                    processed_values[9]="None"

            elif(i==10):
                for j in range(len(list_to_sort)):
                    if(list_to_sort[j]=="city"):
                        processed_values[10]=(list_to_sort[j])
                        processed_values[11]=(list_to_sort[j+1])

                if(processed_values[10] != "city"):
                    processed_values[10]="city"
                    processed_values[11]="None"
        except:
            print("failed to append!")
    return processed_values

    # Converts desired data fields to a string delimitting values by ','
def to_CSV(values_to_convert):
    CSV_ENTRY=str(values_to_convert[1])+','+str(values_to_convert[3])+','+str(values_to_convert[5])+','+str(values_to_convert[7])+','+str(values_to_convert[9])+','+str(values_to_convert[11])
    return CSV_ENTRY


with open("CommaOnly.txt", 'r') as c:
    print("Starting.. :)")

    for line in c:
        entry = c.readline()
        to_sort = split_values(entry)
        now_sorted = reformo_sort(to_sort)
        CSV_ROW=to_CSV(now_sorted)
        with open("sorted_CSV.csv", "a+") as file:
            file.write(str(CSV_ROW)+"\n")

print("Finished! :)")
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: You're importing csv module but using re.split to read the lines. Not very safe, depending on the contents of csv files. Then try to open the CommaOnly.txt in "rb" instead of "r" if you're running on windows. A \r could easily slip undetected, then for each line you open+close your output file: you should open it at startup

Comment: Have you tried printing the returned values from each function? You can find out which function is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the main loop that seems fishy to me, using csv package.

Your reformo_sort routine is incomplet and syntaxically incorrect, with empty elif blocks and missing processing, so I got incomplete lines, but that should work much better than your code. Note the usage of csv, the "binary" flag, the single open in write mode instead of open/close each line (much faster) and the 1-out-of-2 filtering of the now_sorted array.

```
with open("CommaOnly.txt", 'rb') as c:
    print("Starting.. :)")
    cr = csv.reader(c,delimiter=",",quotechar='"')
    with open("sorted_CSV.csv", "wb") as fw:
        cw = csv.writer(fw,delimiter=",",quotechar='"')

        for to_sort in cr:
            now_sorted = reformo_sort(to_sort)
            cw.writerow(now_sorted[1::2])
```

Comment: Wow That Flew FAST! the rb and wb arguments had to be changed to 'r' and 'w' respectively to get the code to work but all data is in tact!

Comment: Glad it works for you, altough not sure of what was causing the problem. Were you by chance writing to a network/NAS drive?